# Problems with detecting repeated values in command line argument in C

Tags: c, duplicates, command-line-arguments

I need a command line argument that takes in 26 unique alphabets (case insensitive). This means that if there is already an 'A', there should not be 'A' or 'a' anymore. I am stuck at detecting repeated values in my command line. Please seek your help to see what is wrong with my code below, it compiles well but still takes in command line argument with repeated values. Thanks in advance!

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Check if user entered one command line argument
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Please input command line argument.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //Check if there are 26 characters.
    if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Please input a valid command line argument (only 26 alphabets).\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //Check if user entered only alphabets in command line argument/
    int p = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < 26; p++)
    {
        if((argv[1][p] >= 'A' && argv[1][p] <= 'Z') || (argv[1][p] >= 'a' && argv[1][p] <= 'z'))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please input a valid command line argument (only 26 alphabets).\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //Reject repeated characters
    int a;
    int b;
    int dup = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < 26; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 26; b++)
        {
            if (toupper(argv[1][a]) == toupper(argv[1][b]))
            {
                dup++;

                if (dup > 1)
                {
                   printf("Please ensure no duplicated characters in command line argument\n");
                   return 1; 
                   break;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `if((argv[1][p] >= 'A' && argv[1][p] <= 'Z') || (argv[1][p] >= 'a' && argv[1][p] <= 'z')) { return 0; }` Try explaining what this does to your nearest rubber duck.

Answer (score 0):

This will return 0 at the first detected character:

```
if((argv[1][p] >= 'A' && argv[1][p] <= 'Z') || (argv[1][p] >= 'a' && argv[1][p] <= 'z'))
{
    return 0;
}
```

Here, at some point you will have a == b at which you will count a duplicate (when you shouldn't):

```
for (a = 0; a < 26; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < 26; b++)
    {
        if (toupper(argv[1][a]) == toupper(argv[1][b]))
        {
```

I hope this helps a bit.